# CSRF protection on Django FormView

Tags: python, django

For example, I use this in **views.py**:

```
@csrf_protect
def contacts(request):
    pass
```

Now I want to use **FormView**:

```
class ContactFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'contacts.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        form.send_email()
        return super(ContactFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

So, where I need to use **@csrf_protect** decorator?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you put {% csrf_token %} inside the form tags in html?

Comment: @Yawar i put in every form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`method_decorator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#id2) on the `dispatch` method:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class ContactFormView(FormView):
    ...
    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ContactFormView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, it's highly recommended to use the `CsrfViewMiddleware` instead. Otherwise, a single instance where you happen to forget the decorator will immediately impose a security risk.

Comment: Thanks! And how to use CsrfViewMiddleware by default?

Comment: You should add `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting. Most project templates, including Django's own project template, already have it included. In that case you can just skip the `csrf_protect` decorator altogether, your views are already protected.